# What does the angle bracket syntax mean in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am reading this book, and it tries to use initializer to Create the DB each time the application runs, so the code snippet is like this:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MusicStoreDB>());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I can't understand this part:

```
 new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MusicStoreDB>()
```

What is this syntax? what does `<MusicStoreDB>()` mean?

I know it's not a fancy question, but I need help here.

Thanks.

Comment: It's `CodeFirst` it means recreate the database whenever the application starts, `MusicStoreDB` is the database

Comment: Hi toby, I know it's code first, I don't understand the C# syntax itself.

Comment: If you do not understand C# syntax then it is probably better to start with some introductory book on that language before diving into MVC framework

Comment: I understand Generics, but the usage here had me confused, Thanks for others who clarified it in the answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That syntax is called [generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm). In a nutshell (a very tiny nutshell), imagine that your app had more than 1 database (e.g. MusicStoreDB, MovieStoreDB, etc), you could use the same DropCreateDatabaseAlways class with the different db types. In other words, generics let you define classes and functions that can act on many different types, for example

`List<int>, List<string>, List<MyAwesomeClass>`

Comment: Oh ok :) Thanks for explaining .. I hope others would try to help as you do instead of voting questions down , much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

DropCreateDatabaseAlways is the database intializer base class. MusicStoreDB is the database which will be dropped and re-created everytime the application starts. `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MusicStoreDB>()` is the code that does that